# Using Ant, can I change a property name if it already exists?

Tags: ant

I currently have a  batch file that will copy some test results to a directory. That directory will have a date (yyyy-mm-dd). If that date already exists, it will create a new folder with that same date, but append a run number (yyyy-mm-dd run 2, yyyy-mm-dd run 3)

```
@echo off
title Copy the FF results to the results folder

set "date=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%"
set "run="
set "browser=FF"
set "results_paste=C:\TestProject\Results"

:loop
if "%run%"=="1" set "date=%date%_run "
if "%run%"=="1" set "run=2"
if EXIST "%results_paste%\%date%%run%\%browser%\" set /a run+=1&goto loop

REM Create HTML directory and copy results
xcopy "%workspace%\test-output\html\*.*" "%results_paste%\%date%%run%\%browser%\"

REM Create screenshot directory and copy results
xcopy "%workspace%\test-output\XML\screenshots\*.*" "%results_paste%\%date%%run%\XML\screenshots\"
```

How would I accomplish this same functionality using ANT? Here is what I have so far. I'm not sure how to check if the date folder already exists, and if it does, to create a run 2 folder.

```
<project default="CopyResults">

        <property name="Run" value="" />
        <tstamp>
          <format property="Date" pattern="yyyy-mm-dd" locale="en,US,WIN" />
        </tstamp>

        <copy todir="C:/Results/${Date}${Run}/${Project}/${Browser}">
          <fileset dir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/${PROJECT_NAME}/workspace/test-output/html/*.*">
        </copy>

        <dirname property="directoryProperty" file="C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/$PROJECT_NAME/workspace/test-output/${XML}/screenshots"/>
        <mkdir dir="${directoryProperty}"/>

        <copy todir="C:/Results/${Date}${Run}/${Project}/${XML}/screenshots/">
          <fileset dir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/${PROJECT_NAME}/workspace/test-output/${XML}/screenshots/*.*">
        </copy>
```

Comment: Could you give it a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how an example could look like:

```
<project default="CopyResults">

<property name="target" location="c:/temp/anttests"/>
<property name="source" location="C:/temp/source"/>

<target name="CopyResults">

    <tstamp>
      <!-- uppercase M is month -->
      <format property="Date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" locale="en,US,WIN" />
    </tstamp>

    <!-- calculate increment number -->
    <resourcecount property="Run">
        <dirset dir="${target}">
            <include name="${Date}*"/>
        </dirset>
    </resourcecount>


    <copy todir="${target}/${Date}${Run}/">
      <fileset dir="${source}">
        <include name="**/*"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- rest goes here -->
</target>
```

the resourcecount task does the magic. In the dirset all directories with the date and optional number are selected. this is the value for Run

Hope this helps.